# Facebook sharer underneath facebook video

Tags: facebook, embed, facebook-sharer

I have a facebook video embedded in a fan page tab.  You can click to share a message but the dialog that pops up appears underneath the video itself.  I had a screenshot to show you but it won't let me post it because I don't have enough rep.

Is there a way to have the sharing message above the video?  I have tried z-index in css and that didn't work.  I also tried adding these tags to the embed code:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
wmode="transparent" (in the actual embed tag)
```

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to use `wmode="opaque"` as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/